# What kind of lock do I need to lock this sliding door from the outside?

Tags: lock, sliding-glass-door

I have a sliding door in my home that says "Fleetwood" and looks like this:

[image]

The outside plate looks like this:

[image]

What kind of a lock is supposed to be used in this door to allow it to be locked from the outside? Bonus question: can I install one of the more advanced locks on this door, such as as a fingerprint-based one?

Comment: It's a sliding glass door. Unless you want it pried open, put a broomstick (or fancy broomstick substitute locking bar) inside to jam it closed and exit/enter via some other door when going away from the house. (Virtually) All sliding glass doors are remarkably easy to simply pry to the point the locks break (breaking the glass is rarely resorted to.) Got hit by thieves that way in a rental house...

Comment: @Ecnerwal It's cheaper to have the lock broken by theives than the glass.  locks only keep honest people honest.

Comment: @Ecnerwal if someone wants to break in, there are plenty of decorative rocks on the outside they could smash the glass with instead of bothering with the lock :) I'm not too worried about robberies, just want something that will protect against a random bored intruder.

Comment: In other words you want to prevent the neighborhood kids from raiding the liquor cabinet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ended up contacting one of Fleetwood's dealers and obtained a spare lock for my particular door model. You can find photos of the lock in a related question: [What kind of cylinder do I need for this type of lock?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/210000/what-kind-of-cylinder-do-i-need-for-this-type-of-lock).

It's possible that this lock could be obtained elsewhere, but I couldn't figure out which tailpiece fits this particular door type so I ended up getting one from the manufacturer.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.prioritydoorwindow.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Aluminum_Products.pdf suggests that keyed locks are only an option on the Fleetwood 3000/3000-T line, not the 1000 line (which is the only one that is not named "luxury").

I don't know how to tell the model, but it looks like the 1000 series doesn't have keyed locks as a manufacturer option.  If you do have 3000/3000-T, could see if they offer it as as a replacement SKU.

I've not heard of third-party locks for this kind of equipment, but maybe someone else will have some other ideas.